# What is the usage of ICU and Freetype?

Tags: icu, freetype

I want to convert given English characters to Hindi. For example there is a name like John in English it has to be converted to Hindi जॉन. Can I use Freetype and ICU for that? I want in Linux and C platform.

Answer (score 1):

Freetype is for rendering, but from a text perspective you can use [ICU Transforms](http://userguide.icu-project.org/transforms/general) such as `Latin-Devanagari`. you can try the [demo](http://demo.icu-project.org/icu-bin/translit) also.